# Formatting a Windows 8 drive to install Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-installation

I have problems with my Windows 8 due to compatibility issues with some of my applications. I need remove this Windows 8 and install Windows 7.

How do I do this?

Comment: using bootable windows 7 disk or bootable pen driver

Comment: Do you already have Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to ask then bring your computer to a reputable shop and get them to downgrade for you.  Depending on the edition of Windows 8 you are licensed with Windows 7 might be free.  That is called "Downgrade Rights."  If you do not qualify for that however then you will need to purchase a separate Windows 7 license and those run around USD$100.

Answer (score 0):

Create a partition which is about 40-50GB (just for now) then put your install CD/USB device in, boot from it and install to the partition you made, format the windows 8 partition, then change the size of the other partition.